# Is there a way to unwrap a Tclkit packed exe?

Tags: tcl, word-wrap, starkit

I have an exe that has been wrapped using this method:
http://www.kocjan.org/tclmentor/10-tclkits-building-standalone-tcl-binaries.html

Is there any way to unpack it back into a .kit file or a vfs structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `sdx` tool, downloadable in kit form from [equi4](http://www.equi4.com/pub/sk/). For example, to list the contents of a starkit:

```
tclkit sdx.kit lsk $yourfile.kit
```

And to unpack it (into a directory called `yourfile.vfs`; you can't control that):

```
tclkit sdx.kit unwrap $yourfile.kit
```

Starpacks work just the same as starkits in the above, but end up also listing or unpacking a copy of Tcl's support files (plus the other packages that were already in the tclkit used to build the pack) too.

Comment: I tried that, it's an exe now, not a kit. I need to turn it from an exe into a kit.

Comment: Well, `unwrap` unwraps both kits and exes (provided they're starpacks; it can't unwrap non-starpacks!) after which it is up to you to then remove the bits you don't want in the kit and `sdx wrap` them back up again into a kit archive.

Comment: I assumed that they were Starpack as I don't know of any other way to wrap Tcl/Tk code into an EXE. Do you know of any other ways?

Comment: @download: There are indeed other ways. Ask that as a separate full question!